# Method not performing well

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parameters, static-methods

I'm new to iPhone dev, and very rusty with C-style programming, namely pointers. I made a RGBColor class that holds three ints for red, green, and blue. In this class, I have a static method to return a UIColor for three RGB int values. I use that method to change the background color from three sliders.

Here is the static method:

```
+(UIColor *)getColorFromRed:(int)redValue green:(int)greenValue blue:(int)blueValue
{
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:redValue/256
                                           green:greenValue/256
                                            blue:blueValue/256
                                           alpha:1.0];
    return color;
}
```

I initially coded the method like this but changed it when it didn't work:

```
+(UIColor *)getColorFromRGB:(int)redValue :(int)greenValue :(int)blueValue
{
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:redValue/256
                                           green:greenValue/256
                                            blue:blueValue/256
                                           alpha:1.0];
    return color;
}
```

Based on my understanding, either the first or the second is a valid way to write a method.

Now, I use this method to change the background color in my view with my changeBackgroundColor function, but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)changeBackgroundColor
{
    UIColor *color = [RGBColor getColorFromRed:redSlider.value
                                         green:greenSlider.value
                                          blue:blueSlider.value];

    [background setBackgroundColor:color];
}
```

If I completely bypass my static method, and just have the changeBackgroundColor method create the UIColor, the background color changes.

```
- (void)changeBackgroundColor
{
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:redSlider.value/256
                                           green:greenSlider.value/256
                                            blue:blueSlider.value/256
                                           alpha:1.0];

    [background setBackgroundColor:color];
}
```

The problem is trivial to solve: just don't use the static method. I just don't understand why it doesn't work. Is there some sort of pointer vs object transfer I'm messing up with the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the slider's value is of type `float` and when you pass it to your static method they are converted to be of type `int` (since the arguments type is `int`) which means that when you divide by 256 the result is truncated to zero because you are dividing an `int` with and `int` (I assume your slider values are always < 256 so the integer part will always be zero).

Just change your static method argument types to `float`

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: when you divide and int with and int only the integer part of the result is returned. (so any division of x/y where x < y will produce 0 as the result). And your floats are cast to an int when you pass them to the method.

Answer (score 1):

int/int give integer.... type case either one to float so that 0.0 to 1.0 value would come, otherwise 255/256 will give you 0, acutally it would be 0.9 something and as target is int, only integer part will be considered, resulting it in 0.

```
+(UIColor *)getColorFromRGB:(float)redValue :(float)greenValue :(float)blueValue
{
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:redValue/256.0
                                           green:greenValue/256.0
                                            blue:blueValue/256.0
                                           alpha:1.0];
    return color;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was a simple calculation problem. I'm embarrassed. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it said the other one was posted first. I would upvote but I can't yet. Thanks though!